# Check if Pandas DataFrame cell contains certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Suppose I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
     a               b
0  NAN  BABA UN EQUITY
1  NAN            2018
2  NAN            2017
3  NAN            2016
4  NAN             NAN
5  NAN   700 HK EQUITY
6  NAN            2018
7  NAN            2017
8  NAN            2016
9  NAN             NAN
```

For each cell in column `b`, I want to check if it contains the string `EQUITY`. If it does, I want to replace the cells in column `a`, the next row with the previous string until a row that is `NAN`, to get the edited DataFrame as follows:

```
                a               b
0             NAN  BABA UN EQUITY
1  BABA UN EQUITY            2018
2  BABA UN EQUITY            2017
3  BABA UN EQUITY            2016
4             NAN             NAN
5             NAN   700 HK EQUITY
6   700 HK EQUITY            2018
7   700 HK EQUITY            2017
8   700 HK EQUITY            2016
9             NAN             NAN
```

My actual DataFrame is much larger than the above, but the format is similar. I am having trouble figuring out how to check whether a cell contains `EQUITY`. It seems that `str.contains` is what I should be using, but it's not clear to me how to do that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN'],
 'b': ['BABA UN EQUITY', '2018', '2017', '2016', 'NAN', '700 HK EQUITY', '2018', '2017', '2016', 'NAN']})

# Make sure that all NaN values are `np.nan` not `'NAN'` (strings)
df = df.replace('NAN', np.nan)
mask = df['b'].str.contains(r'EQUITY', na=True)
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = df['b']
df['a'] = df['a'].ffill()
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = np.nan
```

yields

```
                a               b
0             NaN  BABA UN EQUITY
1  BABA UN EQUITY            2018
2  BABA UN EQUITY            2017
3  BABA UN EQUITY            2016
4             NaN             NaN
5             NaN   700 HK EQUITY
6   700 HK EQUITY            2018
7   700 HK EQUITY            2017
8   700 HK EQUITY            2016
9             NaN             NaN
```

---

One slightly tricky bit above is how `mask` is defined. Notice that `str.contains`
returns a Series which contains not only `True` and `False` values, but also `NaN`:

```
In [114]: df['b'].str.contains(r'EQUITY')
Out[114]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4      NaN
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9      NaN
Name: b, dtype: object
```

`str.contains(..., na=True)` is used to make the `NaN`s be treated as `True`:

```
In [116]: df['b'].str.contains(r'EQUITY', na=True)
Out[116]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

---

Once you have `mask` the idea is simple: Copy the values from `b` into `a` wherever `mask` is True:

```
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = df['b']
```

Forward-fill the NaN values in `a`:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].ffill()
```

Replace the values in `a` with NaN wherever `mask` is True:

```
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Can you use `na=True` argument to `str.contains` instead of `!= False` ? (Or `na=False` as required.)

Comment: @jpp: You are absolutely right. I had forgotten that parameter existed.

Comment: I'm having a problem when checking if one or other pattern is contained in a string.
See this:
`pattern='wiring | media | elect | tape'`
`v=pd.Series(['electricity fault'])`

`s=v.str.contains(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)`
`print(s)`
`[Out]`
`0    False`
`dtype: bool`
   Why?
I would really appreciate if you could help me

Comment: I think I solved. But not sure why? 
Could it be because of the spaces in the pattern?
See this: 
`pattern='wiring |media|elect|tape' `
`v=pd.Series(['electricity fault']) s=v.str.contains(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)`
Output
`0    True`

Comment: @pink.slash: spaces are characters too. ` elect ` matches a space followed by `elect` followed by a space. The string `'electricity fault'` does not have spaces before or after `elect`, so there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. List comprehension is faster than `str.contains`

Even though they're vectorized, Pandas string methods are not optimized, so falling back to Python loops is often much faster, even for large dataframes.

For example, the following two are equivalent (yet the list comprehension is approx. 3 times faster no matter the length of the column):

```py
msk1 = df['b'].str.contains(r'EQUITY', na=True)

msk = [s != s or 'EQUITY' in s for s in df['b'].tolist()]

all(msk == msk1)   # True
```

That said, `str.contains` is (arguably) much more readable; besides both versions perform very fast and unlikely to be a bottleneck for performance of a code.

###### 2. For multiple strings, use `"|".join`

To check if any of a list of strings exist in rows of a column, join them with a `|` separator and call `str.contains`:

```py
lst = ['EQUITY', '16', '19', '20']
msk = df['b'].str.contains(r'|'.join(lst), na=True)
```

##### 3. Filtering can be done with `where()` and `mask()`

The final desired output may be reached by masking certain values in column `b` using the boolean mask `msk`. First step is to remove the nonmatched values (numbers in the example in the OP) using `where()`; then propagate values using `ffill()`; finally, remove the values where the condition is True using `mask()`.

```py
msk = df['b'].str.contains(r'EQUITY', na=True)
df['a'] = df['b'].where(msk).ffill().mask(msk)
```

[image: transformation]